# What is my mistake?Android app

Tags: android

First My application is open MainActivity then i click to button and open problem`s activity

Is my Log

```
12-21 18:41:18.947 27694-27694/tj.tajdev.mrking.whatisonindushanbe E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-21 18:41:18.947 27694-27694/tj.tajdev.mrking.whatisonindushanbe E/AndroidRuntime: Process: tj.tajdev.mrking.whatisonindushanbe, PID: 27694
12-21 18:41:18.947 27694-27694/tj.tajdev.mrking.whatisonindushanbe E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: file
12-21 18:41:18.947 27694-27694/tj.tajdev.mrking.whatisonindushanbe E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.net.Uri.fromFile(Uri.java:452)
12-21 18:41:18.947 27694-27694/tj.tajdev.mrking.whatisonindushanbe E/AndroidRuntime:     at tj.tajdev.mrking.whatisonindushanbe.AdderProduct.AdderActivity2.getOutputMediaFileUri(AdderActivity2.java:222)
12-21 18:41:18.947 27694-27694/tj.tajdev.mrking.whatisonindushanbe E/AndroidRuntime:     at tj.tajdev.mrking.whatisonindushanbe.AdderProduct.AdderActivity2.captureImage(AdderActivity2.java:107)
12-21 18:41:18.947 27694-27694/tj.tajdev.mrking.whatisonindushanbe E/AndroidRuntime:     at tj.tajdev.mrking.whatisonindushanbe.AdderProduct.AdderActivity2.access$000(AdderActivity2.java:22)
12-21 18:41:18.947 27694-27694/tj.tajdev.mrking.whatisonindushanbe E/AndroidRuntime:     at tj.tajdev.mrking.whatisonindushanbe.AdderProduct.AdderActivity2$1.onClick(AdderActivity2.java:61)
12-21 18:41:18.947 27694-27694/tj.tajdev.mrking.whatisonindushanbe E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
12-21 18:41:18.947 27694-27694/tj.tajdev.mrking.whatisonindushanbe E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
12-21 18:41:18.947 27694-27694/tj.tajdev.mrking.whatisonindushanbe E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
12-21 18:41:18.947 27694-27694/tj.tajdev.mrking.whatisonindushanbe E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-21 18:41:18.947 27694-27694/tj.tajdev.mrking.whatisonindushanbe E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
12-21 18:41:18.947 27694-27694/tj.tajdev.mrking.whatisonindushanbe E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
12-21 18:41:18.947 27694-27694/tj.tajdev.mrking.whatisonindushanbe E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-21 18:41:18.947 27694-27694/tj.tajdev.mrking.whatisonindushanbe E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
12-21 18:41:18.947 27694-27694/tj.tajdev.mrking.whatisonindushanbe E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

My Activity

```
public class AdderActivity2 extends Activity {
        private static final String TAG = AdderActivity2.class.getSimpleName();
        private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
        private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
        public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
        public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;
        private Uri fileUri; // file url to store image/video
        private Button btnCapturePicture, btnRecordVideo;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(getResources().getString(R.color.action_bar))));
            btnCapturePicture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapturePicture);
            btnRecordVideo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRecordVideo);
            btnRecordVideo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            btnCapturePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // capture picture
                    captureImage();
                }
            });
 btnRecordVideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // record video
                    recordVideo();
                }
            });
            if (!isDeviceSupportCamera()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! Your device doesn't support camera",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // will close the app if the device does't have camera
                finish();
            }
        }
        private boolean isDeviceSupportCamera() {
            if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                    PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
                // this device has a camera
                return true;
            } else {
                // no camera on this device
                return false;
            }
        }
        private void captureImage() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
        private void recordVideo() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
            fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            outState.putParcelable("file_uri", fileUri);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
            fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
        }
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    launchUploadActivity(true);

                } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }

            } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    launchUploadActivity(false);

                } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "User cancelled video recording", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();

                } else {
                    // failed to record video
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Sorry! Failed to record video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        }

        private void launchUploadActivity(boolean isImage){
            Intent i = new Intent(AdderActivity2.this, UploadActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("filePath", fileUri.getPath());
            i.putExtra("isImage", isImage);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
            return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
        }
        private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {
                            .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                    Config.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);
            if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
                if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Oops! Failed create "
                            + Config.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
                    return null;
                }
            }
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                    Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
            File mediaFile;
            if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
                mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                        + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
            } else if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
                mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                        + "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
            } else {
                return null;
            }

            return mediaFile;
        }
    }
```

how to fix it? My application capture image and send to server 
please help, help
Permision is true.
What is my mistake ?
Mybe problem with them of it activity?
and php code too is true

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not added location permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: I have it permission too